# Deploying flutter app to app store (ios) in windows

Tags: ios, flutter

I have finished developing with my application and deployed to playstore. How do I do the same for ios? I don't have a MacBook.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, to build a flutter iOS app you need a Mac.

But what you can do is use external tools.

One of these tools is Odevio (https://github.com/Odevio/Odevio-CLI). It's a tool that lets you access remote MacOS build machines.

It is really easy to use, just visit:

https://www.odevio.com

Link your Apple developper account with Odevio. https://odevio-cli.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/6_configure_app_store_connect.html

Finally, you can start your build in the build menu.

And that's it.

Answer (score 0):

To deploy an app to the AppStore you need Xcode, so MacBook is required.

I heard some people that don't have Mac use **Cloud MacOS**, but its risky, so do your own research.

Answer (score 0):

You can archive this by cicd code magic. [Reference link](https://blog.codemagic.io/how-to-build-and-distribute-ios-apps-without-mac-with-flutter-codemagic/)

you have to check all the functionality once before uploading app to app store to avoid app rejection. Development of iOS app without MacOs its difficult. For development you must require xcode & Mac os.